# Need help understanding what this Regex will match

Tags: regex, html

I am not sure what this Regex means.

```
pattern="^[\w\s-\'\.]${1,0}"
```

Can someone provide suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The given Regular Expression is probably wrong.
It's right till here : `^[\w\s-\'\.]$`
The line actually ends at `$`.
Why would you need that `{0,1}` ?

Anyway, here's the explanation for the right part :
`^` asserts position at start of the string
`[\w\s-\'\.]` Match a single character present in the list below
`\w` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
`\s` matches any white-space character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
`-` matches the character **-** literally (case sensitive)
`\'` matches the character **'** literally (case sensitive)
`\.` matches the character **.** literally (case sensitive)
`$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)